# Same data, different regression output, R

Tags: r

I try to estimate a model in R with lagged variables. Here are 2 regression specification (identical, just using different approaches):

```
a1 <- lm(premium ~ lag(dp), data = predictor_data1)
b1 <- lm(predictor_data1[,1] ~ lag(predictor_data1[,2]))
```

The first regression refers to variable by name, the second -- by corresponding column in data.frame.

Here is the data:

```
head(predictor_data1)

premium        dp        dy        ep         de         svar csp       b.m       ntis    tbl     ltr    lty
1926-12-01  0.023247 -2.973012        NA -2.386837 -0.5861751 0.0004646178 NaN 0.4414758 0.05087618 0.0307  0.0078 0.0354
1927-01-01 -0.005410 -2.942374 -2.963349 -2.374773 -0.5676012 0.0004698947 NaN 0.4437056 0.05082378 0.0323  0.0075 0.0351
1927-02-01  0.042922 -2.979535 -2.932946 -2.430353 -0.5491819 0.0002873343 NaN 0.4285009 0.05166764 0.0329  0.0088 0.0347
1927-03-01  0.004324 -2.976535 -2.970053 -2.445079 -0.5314564 0.0009241928 NaN 0.4697651 0.04635658 0.0320  0.0253 0.0331
1927-04-01  0.010521 -2.984225 -2.967143 -2.471309 -0.5129164 0.0006025886 NaN 0.4567541 0.05051402 0.0339 -0.0005 0.0333
1927-05-01  0.059353 -3.025963 -2.975058 -2.531446 -0.4945175 0.0003917338 NaN 0.4347826 0.05527539 0.0333  0.0109 0.0327
               tms         infl
1926-12-01  0.0047  0.000000000
1927-01-01  0.0028 -0.011299440
1927-02-01  0.0018 -0.005714286
1927-03-01  0.0011 -0.005747126
1927-04-01 -0.0006  0.000000000
1927-05-01 -0.0006  0.005780347
```

and here is the summary:

```
summary(a1)
Call:
lm(formula = premium ~ lag(dp), data = predictor_data1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.28744 -0.02662  0.00254  0.02773  0.41043 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.018464   0.011652  -1.585   0.1133  
lag(dp)     -0.007484   0.003393  -2.206   0.0276 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05418 on 1139 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.004253,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.003379 
F-statistic: 4.865 on 1 and 1139 DF,  p-value: 0.02761


summary(b1)

Call:
lm(formula = predictor_data1[, 1] ~ lag(predictor_data1[, 2]))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.29828 -0.02658  0.00369  0.02921  0.40126 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)               0.025923   0.011686   2.218   0.0267 *
lag(predictor_data1[, 2]) 0.005571   0.003404   1.637   0.1020  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05426 on 1138 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.002349,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.001472 
F-statistic: 2.679 on 1 and 1138 DF,  p-value: 0.102
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can we please have a *reproducible* example?

Comment: You have different degrees of freedom, and a message in second model that one obs was dropped, check why (probably `NA`s). Also note that if you do `predictor_data1[,x]`, by default R coerces a matrix with one column to a vector, try setting the flag `predictor_data1[,x,drop=FALSE]`. BTW for safety reasons always use `stats::lag()` instead of `lag()`, unfortunately `dplyr` masks it if you use it.

Comment: Yes, there is 1 NA, the first one should be dropped since it is a *LAG*

Comment: Running your exact code with the exact data you have supplied in your question results in `a1` and `b1` having exactly the same values.

Comment: @jay.sf my impression is that the dplyr lag returns result in a form that I expect while base::lag does not.

Comment: @IRTFM I know what you mean, maybe OP actually uses dplyr::lag. Anyway, I have my own `lag` in my personal package that I use.

Comment: @AlekseyKipriyanov You probably do want `dplyr::lag`, write it like this.

Comment: Actually, I managed to solve the issue! The thing was that initially I read Excel to download the data, an I had xts. When I converted the predictor_data to data.frame, both ways begin to give same outcome.